# Feasibility of using both optional and multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.3

Just wondering if it is possible to use both an optional argument in the same function as multiple arguments. I've looked around and I feel as if I just have the vocabulary wrong or something. Example:

```
def pprint(x, sub = False, *Headers):
  pass
```

Can I call it still using the multiple headers without having to always put `True` or `False` in for sub?  I feel like it's a no because `Headers` wouldn't know where it begins.  I'd like to explicitly state that `sub = True` otherwise it defaults to `False`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, use:

```
def pprint(x, *headers, sub=False):
    pass
```

putting the keyword arguments *after* the positionals. This syntax will not work in Python 2.

Demo:

```
>>> def pprint(x, *headers, sub=False):
...     print(x, headers, sub)
... 
>>> pprint('foo', 'bar', 'baz', sub=True)
foo ('bar', 'baz') True
>>> pprint('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
foo ('bar', 'baz') False
```

You *must* specify a different value for `sub` using a keyword argument when calling the `pprint()` function defined here.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say yes because lots of matplotlib (for example) methods have something similar to this...

For example,

`matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr(x, y, normed=True, detrend=<function detrend_none at 0x2523ed8>, usevlines=True, maxlags=10, hold=None, **kwargs)`

When I'm using this I can specify any of the keyword arguments by saying `maxlags=20` for example. You **do** have to specify all the non-keyworded arguments (so `x` in your case) before the keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
def pprint(x, **kwargs):
    sub = kwargs.get('sub', False)
    headers = kwargs.get('headers', [])
```